# CupertinoPicker textStyle flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-cupertino, cupertinopicker

I'm new to [flutter](https://flutter.dev/) and I need help.

I'm creating an app where the user can select data through a [CupertinoPicker](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoPicker-class.html).

The picker works fine, but I would like to change its style.

Currently the style is like [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9IQ0.png), but I want it to be like [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKx4u.png).

Unfortunately I can't understand how to do it, I read [this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoTextThemeData/pickerTextStyle.html) but I can't do it, I would like to change the color and size of the selected element, the color of the elements not selected and the color of the lines.

But I do not know how I can do it.

Can anyone help me understand please?

**The code is this** :

```
Container(

          ˙child: _showCupertinoPicker(
           context,
           book[currentPage].orari.map((orario) {
           return Center(
                     child: Text(orario,
                     style: TextStyle(color: CupertinoColors.activeBlue

                         )));
           }).toList())),
.
.
.
.

_showCupertinoPicker(BuildContext context, List<Widget> orariWidget) {
  return CupertinoPicker(
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    onSelectedItemChanged: (value) {},
    itemExtent: 40.0,
    children: orariWidget,
  );
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Its possible to style `CupertinoPicker` and `CupertinoDatePicker` using theme like this:

```
return MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
    cupertinoOverrideTheme: CupertinoThemeData(
      textTheme: CupertinoTextThemeData(
        dateTimePickerTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontSize: 16),
        pickerTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontSize: 12),
      )
    )
  )
)
```

Answer (score 6):

Wrap the CupertinoPicker() with another widget known as CupertinoTheme()
as

```
CupertinoTheme(
     data: CupertinoThemeData(
         textTheme: CupertinoTextThemeData(
             pickerTextStyle: TextStyle(//Your normal TextStyling)
         ),
     ),
     child:CupertinoPicker(//Your Cupertino Picker)
)
```

Comment: Better example than the chosen answer.

Comment: dateTimePickerTextStyle should be used instead of pickerTextStyle. Here is a scenario where pickerTextStyle doesn't work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67579890/changing-the-text-color-of-cupertino-date-picker

Answer (score 3):

I know this solution is verbose but it works:

```dart
final cupertinoTheme = CupertinoTheme.of(context);
// Do your customising here:
final pickerTextStyle =
    cupertinoTheme.textTheme.pickerTextStyle.copyWith(fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.cyan);
final textTheme =
    cupertinoTheme.textTheme.copyWith(pickerTextStyle: pickerTextStyle);
return CupertinoTheme(
  data: cupertinoTheme.copyWith(textTheme: textTheme),
  child: yourPickerGoesHere,
);
```

`CupertinoPicker` takes text style from `CupertinoTheme.of(context).textTheme.pickerTextStyle`. All we do here is to update `pickerTextStyle` with our settings.

Comment: Not sure who downvoted this or why, this is the only answer that worked for me. The other answers give me a scrunched-in date picker where the month, year, and date overlap. I still had to wrap the date picker in a SizedBox with desired height and a width at least the size of the parent widget. Also, had to use dateTimePickerTextStyle instead of pickerTextStyle