# Flutter's Cupertino Date Picker Color Customization

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-test

Can or how can the Cupertino Date Picker's gray highlight bar in Flutter be changed to another color? And the corners be not rounded?

[image: Cupertino DatePicker Example]

Comment: refer here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67579890/changing-the-text-color-of-cupertino-date-picker

Comment: hi @gretal, thanks for the link but this is for changing the text color. Not the color of the rectangle bar that is gray by default. :)

Comment: why don't you use this date picker: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50321182/how-to-customize-a-date-picker

Comment: hi @gretal, because the UI specified looks like the Cupertino Date Picker.

Comment: Did anyone ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding this property to my CupertinoPicker:

selectionOverlay: CupertinoPickerDefaultSelectionOverlay(
background: Colors.transparent,
),

```
CupertinoPicker(
                  selectionOverlay: CupertinoPickerDefaultSelectionOverlay(
                    background: Colors.transparent,
                  ),
                  looping: true,
                  itemExtent: 25,
                  scrollController:
                      FixedExtentScrollController(initialItem: hours - 1),
                  onSelectedItemChanged: (value) {
                    hours = value + 1;
                    print(hours);
                    setState(() {});
                  },
                  children: List.generate(
                      12,
                      (index) => Text(
                            "${index + 1}".padLeft(2, '0'),
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: index + 1 == hours
                                  ? Colors.white
                                  : Colors.black,
                            ),
                          ))),
```